# wiringPi works only with pin 7

Tags: raspberry-pi2, led, wiringpi

I have this simple code on Raspberry B+.

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  int pin;
  if (argc <2) 
     pin = 7;
  else
     pin = atoi(argv[1]);
  printf("Raspberry Pi wiringPi blink test\n");

  if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
    return 1;

  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);

  for (;;){
    printf("LED On\n");
    digitalWrite(pin, 1);
    delay(250);
    printf("LED Off\n");
    digitalWrite(pin, 0);
    delay(250);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I want to blink a LED connected to a certain pin.
But for some reason the led is blinking only when connected to pin 7. (I have not tried all other pins though, just 8,31,32,33);
when I try the command `gpio -g 6 write 1` (which is for pin 31) the LED glows...
What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out!

The wiringPi pin numbering is different from R-Pi!
[Here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-gpio) is a chart for which pin is which.

It was just a coincidence that pin 7 on R-Pi is pin 7 on wiringPi as well.